# Magento select product image from media manager or something

Tags: magento

Ahoy, everyone.

I am new to Magento and I am trying to achieve is that I want some type of media library like Woocommerce have. When I create the product I want to select the product image form the media manager.

Is there any extension out there or should I have to create it from scratch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?